# Extracting time series from AllenSDK ephy data base

Tags: python, allen-sdk

I am looking to AllenSDK library. Can one extract time series (voltage of the cell in time) of the recordings they did to estimate various parameters? I can find how to access the parameters but I am really interested in their traces.
Anyone can help with that?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to 
https://allensdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cell_types.html#feature-extraction to get dataset and the sweet metadata. Then you can access sweep timeseries like so:

```
for sweep_number in sweep_numbers:
    data = dataset.get_sweep(sweep_number)
    v = data['response'] * 1e3 # mV
    i = data['stimulus'] * 1e12 # pA
    hz = data['sampling_rate']
```